# Set fixed screen width in angular flex-layout

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using https://github.com/angular/material2 and https://github.com/angular/flex-layout in an angular2 app, I want to set the screen to a fixed width instead of using the whole available width of the screen.

The equivalent in bootstrap 4 would be to use

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

as shown here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/

Currently the layout spans the whole screen. 
My question: I would like it to only span a certain width. How would I do that? Here is the current html snippet I use.

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" (click)="goHome()">
  <span>
      Democratizer    
  </span>
</md-toolbar>
<div class="app-content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

You can find the original here: https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer-angular/blob/master/frontend-angular/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at material design page, https://material.io/guidelines/ it use this kind of resource, as it seems they do it manually in `@media` tag fixing the `width` and using `margin: auto`